# Dynamic navbar using React.js

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, react-context

I am trying to create a navbar, in which three components will show but dynamically for example:

if user is not logged in then navbar will show only three components in navlinks and they will be:

1. About
2. login
3. Signup

if user is logged in then navbar will show only three components in navlinks that will be:

1. About
2. Dashboard
3. Logout (i.e a button)

I am new to react and dont know what to do.

**What I am doing:**

**login.jsx**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../UserContext";
import {Link, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import "./login.css";

class Login extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email:"",
            password:"",
            token:"",
            user:[],
            loggedIn:false
        };
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    componentDidMount() {

    }
    
    login = (e) => {
        const {email,password}=this.state;
        const rawurl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/user/login';
        const url = rawurl;
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ email:email,password:password })
        };
        e.preventDefault();
            fetch(url,requestOptions)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this.setState({ user: [data], loaded: true });
                    localStorage.setItem('userData',JSON.stringify(this.state.user));
                    localStorage.setItem('token',JSON.stringify(this.state.user[0].token))
                    this.setState({token:localStorage.getItem('token')})
                    console.log(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
                    this.setState({loggedIn:true});
                })
                .catch(err => console.log("error ", err))

    }
    render() {
        if(this.state.loggedIn==true){
            return <Redirect to="/dashboard/read"></Redirect>
        } 
        return (
            <div id="login">
                <div class="slide-in-elliptic-right-fwd">
                    Welcome to Login Page
                </div><br/>
                <div id="loginForm" class="scale-in-hor-center">
                    <form>
                        <input type="email" name="email" value={this.state.email} placeholder="Email" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                        <input type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password} placeholder="Password" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                        <button onClick={this.login} id="loginButton" class="bounce-in-top">Login</button>
                        ........or........
                       <Link to="/signup" class="bounce-in-top">Signup</Link>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Login;
```

**navbar.jsx**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../UserContext";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import "./navbar.css";
function Navbar() {
    const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
    if(user!=null){
        return(
            <div id="navbar">
            <div class="tracking-in-contract-bck">
                Blogs4You
            </div>
            <div id="navLinks">
                <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                ||
                <Link to="/">Logout</Link>
            </div>
        </div> 
        );
    }
    else{
        return (
            <div id="navbar">
                <div class="tracking-in-contract-bck">
                    Blogs4You
                </div>
                <div id="navLinks">
                    <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                    ||
                    <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                    ||or||
                    <Link to="/signup">Signup</Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Navbar;
```

I have two things in mind i.e. to use api context and the other is localstorage. Kindly help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operation for this type of situation. For this follow the steps

1. when the user login store the user data in local storage. eg `localStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(userData)`.
2. Now in `navbar.jsx` you can use ternary operation statement like eg. `{ (boolean satement)? (code if true):(code if false)}`. By using this you can get user info and can use is inside boolean statement of ternary opration. for your navbar here is an example..

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../UserContext";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import "./navbar.css";
function Navbar() {
    const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
    
    {(user!=null)?
        (
            <div id="navbar">
            <div class="tracking-in-contract-bck">
                Blogs4You
            </div>
            <div id="navLinks">
                <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                ||
                <Link to="/">Logout</Link>
            </div>
        </div> 
        );
   :
     (
            <div id="navbar">
                <div class="tracking-in-contract-bck">
                    Blogs4You
                </div>
                <div id="navLinks">
                    <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                    ||
                    <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                    ||or||
                    <Link to="/signup">Signup</Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    
}
export default Navbar;
```